# How to get current context (logged in entity) objectId

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get current (logged in) service principal\application object id. my code:

```
graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = CLIENT,
        secret = KEY,
        tenant = TENANT_ID,
        resource = "https://graph.windows.net"
    ),
    TENANT_ID
)
for sp in graphrbac_client.service_principals.list():
  if sp.app_id == graphrbac_client.config.credentials.id:
    print('found it')
```

which works, but requires too much permissions for the application (I've only managed to get it work with Directory.ReadAll, doesnt work with [Application.ReadWrite.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-beta), for some reason). All the methods I seem to find seem to require to know objectId upfront... which is what I'm trying to retrieve.

using [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/4350):

```
def resolve_service_principal(identifier):
    """Get an object_id from a client_id.
    """
    graphrbac_credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID'],
        secret=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
        tenant=os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID'],
        resource="https://graph.windows.net"
    )
    graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
        graphrbac_credentials,
        os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']
    )

    result = list(graphrbac_client.service_principals.list(filter="servicePrincipalNames/any(c:c eq '{}')".format(identifier)))
    if result:
        return result[0].object_id
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to get object_id from client_id")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need package 0.50.0 at least and `signed_in_user.get`. Example when I connect with my admin account:

```
user = graphrbac_client.signed_in_user.get()
assert user.mail_nickname.startswith("admin")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/azure.graphrbac.operations.signedinuseroperations?view=azure-python#get-custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-

(I work at Microsoft in this SDK team)

Edit: It seems this works only for User, then I would try:

```
    objects = graphrbac_client.objects.get_objects_by_object_ids({
        'object_ids': [CLIENT],
        'types': ['ServicePrincipal']
    })
```

Comment: i know you work at microsoft and own this code :) (we did talk a lot previously) I tried this method before, and it returns some garbage. let me retry and get back to you. ok, I'm using service principal and it returns this: `azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error_py3.GraphErrorException: Resource not found for the segment 'me'.`. using 0.50.0 exactly. I believe I had the same error with latest

Comment: I must say that I work at MS, I should consider every post I reply as the first post people read from me :). I updated my reply with a second aproach, must admit I didn't try it should be ok.

Comment: it appears I need to add `'include_directory_object_references': False` to the request, but that doesnt help, this returns empty iterator ("End of paging"). I tried setting it to `['Application']`, same deal. any other ideas?

Comment: final idea would be to use the filter parameter of list: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/09718bec64c2155bc179c862dbdf519677321ffd/azure-graphrbac/tests/test_graphrbac.py#L75

Comment: If it's not enough, plese create an SDK issue and I will look at that asap (probably in January). I'll update the response here for the community when we found what we need

Comment: ok, the more i think about it, the more it looks like a weird problem. all the methods require you to know objectId, where as I only know appId

Comment: done, can you maybe take a look at that: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/4350. thanks!